# Write CSV from from a sub split dataframe split by years

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a csv file for a water gage `07223300.csv`that I uploaded into R.

`data_daily <- read.csv(paste0(path_2, "07223300.csv"))`

```
head(data_daily,20)
    X   staid    val      dates qualcode Year_separated 
1   1 7223300  76.00 1970-10-01        A           1970            
2   2 7223300  90.00 1970-10-02        A           1970             
3   3 7223300  94.00 1970-10-03        A           1970             
4   4 7223300 110.00 1970-10-04        A           1970             
5   5 7223300 124.00 1970-10-05        A           1970             
6   6 7223300 140.00 1970-10-06        A           1970             
7   7 7223300 156.00 1970-10-07        A           1970             
8   8 7223300 135.00 1970-10-08        A           1970             
9   9 7223300 117.00 1970-10-09        A           1970             
10 10 7223300 112.00 1970-10-10        A           1970             
11 11 7223300 106.00 1970-10-11        A           1970             
12 12 7223300 112.00 1970-10-12        A           1970             
13 13 7223300 128.00 1970-10-13        A           1970             
14 14 7223300 117.00 1970-10-14        A           1970             
15 15 7223300  47.00 1970-10-15        A           1970             
16 16 7223300   0.37 1970-10-16        A           1970             
17 17 7223300   0.37 1970-10-17        A           1970             
18 18 7223300   0.37 1970-10-18        A           1970             
19 19 7223300   0.19 1970-10-19        A           1970             
20 20 7223300   0.12 1970-10-20        A           1970
```

I managed to split the dataframe into a list split by years ranging from 1970 to 1992.

```
date_str <-as.character(data_daily$dates)
date_substr <-(substr(date_str,1,4))

# Add year column to files
data_daily <-data_daily %>% add_column(Year_separated = date_substr)
data_split <- split(data_daily, data_daily$Year_separated)
```

I would like to change all the values in this list into a csv file.

```
# Path and Name
path_out="D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Subsplit Yearly\\"
file_out <- paste0(names(data_split), ":", "07223300", dat.type)

for(j in 1:length(data_split))
{
  fileName=paste(path_out, file_out, dat.type, sep='')
  write.csv(data_split,fileName)
}
```

Ideally, I would like the output to look like this

```
[1] "1970:07223300.csv" "1971:07223300.csv" "1972:07223300.csv" "1973:07223300.csv" "1974:07223300.csv"
 [6] "1975:07223300.csv" "1976:07223300.csv" "1977:07223300.csv" "1978:07223300.csv" "1979:07223300.csv"
[11] "1980:07223300.csv" "1981:07223300.csv" "1982:07223300.csv" "1983:07223300.csv" "1984:07223300.csv"
[16] "1985:07223300.csv" "1986:07223300.csv" "1987:07223300.csv" "1988:07223300.csv" "1989:07223300.csv"
[21] "1990:07223300.csv" "1991:07223300.csv" "1992:07223300.csv"
```

But when running the for loop, I get this error

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 92, 365, 366, 273
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to specify using the index i.e. `file_out[i]`

Comment: @akrun I tried doing that but I keep getting the same error as before. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: In your code, there is a `dat.type`, which I couldn't understand from the example showed.  If it is a vector of length > 1 i.e. of the same length as file_out, then use `paste(path_out, file_out[j], dat.type[j], sep = "")`.  Earlier, there was a typo.  I thought you had `i`, instead of `j`.

Comment: @akrun `dat.type` was a segment of code added prior to the example shown. 
`dat.type <- ".csv"`

Comment: ok, then you don't need `dat.type[j]`, but, `file.path(path_out, paste0(file_out[j], dat.type))`.

Comment: @akrun ok, so it would be it be `fileName=file.path(path_out,paste0(file_out[j]), dat.type)`

Comment: try that.  I used `file.path` in case there is any issue in the slash

Comment: Where do you get this `write.csv`? AFAIK, `utils::write.csv` in base R cannot write a list of dataframes into CSV files. If it is the base one that you use, try this perhaps: `path_out="D:\\Baylor University\\Texas EFlow Spatial\\Subsplit Yearly\\"; file_out <- paste0(path_out, names(data_split), "-", "07223300", dat.type); for(j in 1:length(data_split)) write.csv(data_split[[j]], file_out[[j]])`. Also, it seems that you are on a Windows system. Note that `:` cannot be used in a file name.